# Contravariant object value in Typescript

Tags: typescript, javascript-objects, typescript-generics, contravariance

Consider the following overloaded Typescript function (attempt):

```
function eraseField(o : Record<"field", string>, nullify : false) : void
function eraseField(o : Record<"field", string | null>, nullify : true) : void
function eraseField(o : any, nullify : any) : void
{
    if (nullify)
    {
        o.field = null;
    }
    else
    {
        o.field = "";
    }
}
```

Now, consider the following object:

```
let o : Record<"field", string> = {"field" : "toBeErased"};
```

Unfortunately, we can do the following without any errors:

```
eraseField(o, true); // 'o.field' is no longer a string, which is against the type declaration.
```

How can I tweak the function declarations/definitions so that the above line of code gives a Typescript error (in strict mode)? In particular, I want to prevent the widening of Record<"field", string>  to Record<"field", string | null> when it is passed to "eraseField", thus effectively making the Record type contravariant for its values in that context.

Comment: Does using a [constrained generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) and a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYlbgm) meet your needs? If so, I can write it as an answer with some explanation. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yup, that apparently does it. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [constrained generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) in your relevant [overload signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), which will allow you to use the compiler's inference to [conditionally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) determine whether the parameter's `field` value allows for a nullable value. In the case that it does, you can accept it — and in the case that it doesn't you can deny its use by setting the parameter's type to `never`:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwE4EMDOyBiNkA2AJgBRwBciASshHKkQDwBEw+xzANIplKjGADmAPm5gQBAjGABPSsHQFsASkoA3ODCIBuAFChIsBCgzY8hJgBUUADyjIwRTNVr0mrdkS48+AwYgAfRHFJYWESXURECkRrZDsHJxc6BhY2C29efiFhRAB+YOQ1NERKS05I4IkpWUo+EGQK1UQNLT0DaHgkNCxcTzJKGhT3dI5uLL9AqtCxauk5RAAjODgCZHQwZUQAb0rpRBIQmpktuAA6UaJEAF5pgj0owmxoi88bxGZmPQBfXV06MC8aIARkGrlSHgy418OXe20Ql0ozCgcAAQsgAKKmZBeRDfPQAoFwABMYOGaU8mRh-iCR1yt3hiI+KPRWN6uPx-wQRIAzGS3BSoXd6TsEZ5KEc8XpdD0zP04MDuAolMhlHpZX0LGRFYh6qrpRrzMQyMSlYoVOrsUbSCTuHq1X9DfKeWaVQ6nVq4C7dagGg6gA)

```ts
function eraseField(o: Record<"field", string>, nullify: false): void;
function eraseField<T extends Record<"field", string | null>>(
  o: T extends Record<"field", string> ? never : T,
  nullify: true,
): void;
function eraseField(o: Record<"field", string | null>, nullify: boolean) {
  if (nullify) o.field = null;
  else o.field = "";
}
```